# What happens to all the stolen neutrons in nuclear reactor?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I'm reading about chain reactions in pressurized water reactors. All is good and clear. U-235 splits, releases 2 or 3 neutrons, if the reactor is supercritical then reaction will continue. Part of the neutrons will escape the reactor, some will be slowed down to split some more U-235.

But what happens with all the captured neutrons within the active zone?

When neutron is captured by U-238 atom, what happens next? Now many neutrons one U-238 atom can capture?

Same with water, H-1 can capture neutron and become deuterium. Primary circuit is a closed system, there is a bunch of water but still finite amount. Can it become 'saturated' with neutrons and capture no more?

This is silly, but the books says that twenty tons of water passes through the core every second. Can neutrons be swept away?

So yeah, what happens to all the stolen neutrons in nuclear reactor? If all the involved parties (materials) capture and keep the neutrons. How much does it affect reactivity eventually, percentagewise?

The book is "How to Drive a Nuclear Reactor" by Colin Tucker and it is great.

Comment: You mean neutrons when you say neuron?

Comment: @amanasci yes, somebody already corrected me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated business. Note that about one third of the neutrons released by fissioning U-235 do get captured by U-238, which gets transmuted to U-236 or plutonium, both of which can then fission and release energy in the reactor. As such, those neutrons are not "stolen".

Neutrons which do not get captured by U-238 can either 1) escape the reactor entirely, 2) bounce off U-238 or U-235 and keep going, or bang into either, lose energy, and then cause the nucleus to emit either a gamma or an x-ray photon.

All these processes (and more) contribute to the *neutron economy* of the reactor (or bomb) which is carefully considered during the design and subsequent operation of the reactor (or bomb).

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, we can say that the neutrons which are not involved in the chain reaction are captured by water, by fuel, by structures, by fission products, this contributing to make radioactive products or chains of radioactive products. Some neutrons can reach the reactor vessel causing damage in the vessel steel. Some, very, very little, high energy can end up outside the vessel.
But for the majority of neutrons in water reactors, their lifespan is very short, 0.003 - 0.004 seconds and their high speed 2200 m / s , their average range is about one meter .
The water current has no mechanical influence on the physics of neutrons.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is what happens to the captured neutrons that do not create fission?  The answer is that they transmute the isotope that absorbed them.
Here are some examples:

- when U-238 captures a neutron, it becomes U-239.  The U-239 can then either split in a fission, stay U-239 for a while, or beta decay.
- when Fe-56 absorbs a neutron, it becomes Fe-57
- When H-1 becomes a neutron, it becomes H-2

Every isotope in the system can potentially absorb a neutron, but some isotopes are "more likely" to absorb neutrons.  The probabilities of capturing a neutron are determined by the "microscopic absorption cross sections" of the material.  Some isotopes (like B-10) are more likely to absorb a neutron than other materials (like H-2).

You ask if the water could ever become saturated as H-2.  Theoretically, yes, but it would take a LOT of neutrons.  The number of free neutrons in a reactor at any one time is going to be something on the order of $10^8$, but the number of water atoms in a single gram is going to be on the order of $10^{23}$.  These are rough numbers, but you can see that they are many orders of magnitude different.  You also have to consider that the H-1 can absorb a neutron and become H-2, and then it can absorb another neutron to become H-3.